# Train ML algorithm to find edges

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, opencv

I have input RGB images as follows:

[image]

I have a dataset of manually annotated images highlighting the outline(edges) from the input images I am attaching an example.

[image]

My aim is to train a ML algorithm which learns how these outlines are mapped. And when given a new image it should produce similar output. Is there any way that this can be done?

Ive tried canny-edge detector,sobel and other type of open cv transforms. But they do not distinct object from their background properly. So I am looking into ML.

Comment: It seems you have tried basic edge detection techniques, can you detail why you are not satisfied with them ?

Answer (score 1):

What You are seeking is called 'Edge detection' in CVML fields.
In my knowledge, DexiNed is one of best models. See papers in paperswithcode.

https://paperswithcode.com/task/edge-detection